# You must include a valid SMS Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, soap

Can anyone explain why the following SOAP request is returning the following response:

"...You must include a valid SMS Triggered Send Definition.033001....

Request (some values replaced for privacy):

```
REQUEST
-------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
   <ns1:CreateRequest>
    <ns1:Options/>
    <ns1:Objects xsi:type="ns1:SMSTriggeredSend">
     <ns1:SMSTriggeredSendDefinition>
      <ns1:CustomerKey>TEST</ns1:CustomerKey>
     </ns1:SMSTriggeredSendDefinition>
     <ns1:Subscriber>
      <ns1:Attributes>
       <ns1:Name>SomeAttrib</ns1:Name>
       <ns1:Value>SomeValue</ns1:Value>
      </ns1:Attributes>
      <ns1:SubscriberKey>61400000000</ns1:SubscriberKey>
     </ns1:Subscriber>
     <ns1:Message>This is just a test</ns1:Message>
     <ns1:Number>61400000000</ns1:Number>
    </ns1:Objects>
   </ns1:CreateRequest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

RESPONSE
--------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <soap:Header>
   <wsa:Action>CreateResponse</wsa:Action>
   <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:xxxxxxxxx-daca-471b-9604-xxxxxxxxxxxx</wsa:MessageID>
   <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:xxxxxxxxxx-780f-4443-85f1-xxxxxxxxxxxx</wsa:RelatesTo>
   <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
   <wsse:Security>
    <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-da21a3b4-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
     <wsu:Created>2014-05-08T13:18:43Z</wsu:Created>
     <wsu:Expires>2014-05-08T13:23:43Z</wsu:Expires>
    </wsu:Timestamp>
   </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
   <CreateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Results>
     <StatusCode>Error</StatusCode>
     <StatusMessage>You must include a valid SMS Triggered Send Definition.</StatusMessage>
     <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
     <ErrorCode>33001</ErrorCode>
     <NewID>0</NewID>
     <Object xsi:type="SMSTriggeredSend">
      <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
      <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
      <SMSTriggeredSendDefinition>
       <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
       <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
       <CustomerKey>TEST</CustomerKey>
      </SMSTriggeredSendDefinition>
      <Subscriber>
       <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
       <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
       <Attributes>
        <Name>SomeAttrib</Name>
        <Value>SomeValue</Value>
       </Attributes>
       <SubscriberKey>61400000000</SubscriberKey>
      </Subscriber>
      <Message>This is just a test</Message>
      <Number>61400000000</Number>
     </Object>
    </Results>
    <RequestID>xxxxxxxxxx-ac5d-4cf2-8a86-xxxxxxxxxxx</RequestID>
    <OverallStatus>Error</OverallStatus>
   </CreateResponse>
  </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Are you using the MobileConnect product?

Comment: Yes I am using the MobileConnect product. If it helps, I'm using this WSDL: https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl

Answer (score 1):

ExactTarget MobileConnect only uses the REST API routes found [here](https://code.exacttarget.com/api/fuel-api-family-sms).

The [SOAP API] is for an older deprecated product.

With MobileConnect enabled, you only have access to the REST API functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The link in the answer from Kelly Andrews is now broken. It looks like they have backed away from their shiny new FuelSDK. No examples of using the SMS stuff exist in their SDK, and all the online help shows the "old" soap version. If some Admin can move this in as a comment to Kelly, that would be great (don't have the rep to comment).